# CSS blend mode for Bootstrap carousel caption

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, background-blend-mode

I am using the carousel component from bootstrap and also want to use the CSS blend-mode `background-blend-mode: multiply;` for the caption.

Unfortunately, the blend mode doesn't work.

The code is the following:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            CAPTION CONTENT
        </div>
        <img src="imgage.png" class="img-responsive" />
     </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is the following:

```
.carousel-caption {
    background-color: rgba(0, 119, 137, 0.7); 
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Is this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to assign the `background-image` property to same selector that you assigning `background-blend-mode`. So this may not work in your case.

[**From the Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode)

> The background-blend-mode CSS property describes how the element's
>   background images should blend with each other and the element's
>   background color.

**Syntax Example:**

```
.blended {
  background-image: url(face.jpg);
  background-color: red;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

---

Along with **`multiply`** you can also use:  `screen`, `overlay`, `darken`, `lighten`, `color-dodge`, `color-burn`, `hard-light`, `soft-light`, `difference`, `exclusion`, `hue`, `saturation`, `color`, and `luminosity`. And also `normal`

*[Source](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/)*

Comment: OK thanks. Unfortunately, this way is not the way the bootstrap slider works :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to blend an element over another, the property that you should use is mix-blend-mode.

It has the same syntax that background-blend-mode, but this one applies only to the in-element backgrounds (as M.Doye says)

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work, **you need to add a background image to the element**. So your code should look like this:

```
.carousel-caption {
   background-image: url('image.png');
   background-color: rgba(0, 119, 137, 0.7); 
   background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

There is a great article [here](https://kolosek.com/css-blend-mode/) you can check out, that gives a further explanation of the blend mode property.